# Open file at project/solution load

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

The company I'm working for delivers visual studio sample .NET projects to the customers. Every project contains windows forms Form and the wish is to show this Form at project load. On my local computer the information about the open files is stored in `*.suo` file, but it is stored as an absolute path.

Is there any way to open a specific file of project on every computer?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather look at [Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ccd9ychb(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @rene sorry no, the goal is just to show to the end user how to use our library. So the customer just have to open the solution and hit debug. But it would be nice to see the form opened in VS editor